# CMD Echo when it starts up?

Tags: cmd, message, echo

How do I change the message that comes up automaticly when I start up CMD? The one where it says:"

---

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6000]

Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.

---

How do I change that automatic message?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By editing the cmd.exe. :) (That was a joke btw, don't really try that)  If you look at a the cmd.exe in a hex editor, you will see that text in it.  There is no easy way that I know of to change it.

Here is an ugly hack to emulate what you are wanting.  First create a .cmd file that contains the following:

```
cmd /k init.bat
```

(cmd /k tells the computer to start an instance of cmd and run the parameter and not exit)

Then created your init.bat file with the following:

```
@echo off
cls
echo My message goes here
```

Then you just run your .cmd file instead of cmd.exe and you will get a command window with just your text at the top.

If I knew why you were wanting to do this, then maybe my answer could have been more specific to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reverse engineer it :) Don't remember exactly how I did, but using a debugger single step until you find the place where it prints that out and edit it. I "hacked" it a bit more and it refuses doing anything, saying "do it yourself!" :)

[image: my hacked cmd.exe]